# Trigger EventHandler of one ViewModel in another ViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I have achieved desired result with MessagingCenter, but I have got an information from reading Xamarin articles that MessagingCenter is not the preferred way to trigger 30+ events. Additional to that I have to unsubscribe from MessagingCenter after action has been done. I want to have Settings page where I would have 30+ settings that have to be changed across whole application in different views. How I can inject SettingsViewModel into other ViewModels in Xamarin.Forms application?

SettingsViewModel.cs:

```
namespace MessagingCenterApp.ViewModels
{
  public class SettingsViewModel : BaseViewModel, ISettingsViewModel
  {
    public ICommand ChangeCommand { get; set; }
    public SettingsViewModel()
    {
      Title = "Settings";

      this.BoxColor = Color.Red;

      this.ChangeCommand = new Command(this.ChangeColor);
    }

    private void ChangeColor()
    {
      this.BoxColor = Color.FromHex(this.BoxColorS);

      MessagingCenter.Send<Object, Color>(this, "boxColor", this.BoxColor);
    }

    private Color _boxColor;
    public Color BoxColor
    {
      get => _boxColor;
      set
      {
        _boxColor = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }

    private string _boxColorS;
    public string BoxColorS
    {
      get => Preferences.Get("BoxColor", "#17805d");
      set
      {
        Preferences.Set("BoxColor", value);
        this.ChangeColor();
        this.OnSettingsChanged();
        this.OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }

    public event EventHandler<SettingsChangedEventArgs> SettingsChanged;
    private void OnSettingsChanged() => this.SettingsChanged?.Invoke(this, new SettingsChangedEventArgs(this.Settings));

    public Settings Settings { get; private set; }
  }
}
```

HomeViewModel.cs:

```
namespace MessagingCenterApp.ViewModels
{
  public class HomeViewModel : BaseViewModel
  {
    public HomeViewModel()
    {
      this.Title = "Home";

      MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object, Color>(this, "boxColor", (sender, arg) =>
      {

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("received color = " + arg);
        this.BoxColor = arg;
      });

      this.BoxColor = Color.Red;

      this.SettingsViewModel = new SettingsViewModel();
      this.SettingsViewModel.SettingsChanged += OnSettingsChanged;
    }

    private void OnSettingsChanged(object sender, SettingsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private Color _boxColor;
    public Color BoxColor
    {
      get => _boxColor;
      set
      {
        _boxColor = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }

    private ISettingsViewModel SettingsViewModel { get; }
  }
}
```

Should I somehow do all in MainViewModel? I mean:

```
namespace MessagingCenterApp.ViewModels
{
  public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
  {
    public MainViewModel()
    {
      this.SettingsViewModel = new SettingsViewModel();
      this.HomeViewModel = new HomeViewModel(this.SettingsViewModel);
    }

    public SettingsViewModel SettingsViewModel { get; set; }
    public HomeViewModel HomeViewModel { get; }
  }
}
```

Then initialized it in AppShell? I could not get this approach working.

Important! I don't want to use any MVVM framework! Only native behaviour.

Comment: Your question title is different from what you ask so... Anyway, you could send some 'abstract' message and potential recipients could act upon that. It'll always be better than tie some VM to another.

Comment: @aybe you mean use MessagingCenter anyway? I think it is not the best option for such a case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mvvmcross' Messenger is alleged to be "lighter weight" than X-Form's built-in Messaging Center.

I use mvvmcross Messenger by defining some helper methods in a "BasePage". Then each page inherits from "BasePage" rather than "ContentPage".

This automatically handles "unsubscribe" of each method. And makes it easier to manage mvvmcross' "subscription tokens".

BasePage.xaml.cs:

```
// If not using mvvmcross, this could inherit from ContentPage instead.
public class BasePage : MvxContentPage
{
    protected readonly IMvxMessenger Messenger;

    public BasePage()
    {
        this.Messenger = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        // Examples of subscribing to messages. Your subclasses of BasePage can also do this.
        this.Subscribe<MyMessage1>(OnMyMessage1);
        this.SubscribeOnMainThread<MyMessage2>(OnMyMessage2);
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        UnsubscribeAll();

        base.OnDisappearing();
    }

    #region Messenger Subscriptions
    protected List<MvxSubscriptionToken> _subscriptions = new List<MvxSubscriptionToken>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Create subscription and add to "_subscriptions".
    /// Call this from subclass' OnAppearing, once per subscription.
    /// Automatically unsubscribed in OnDisappearing.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="token"></param>
    /// <param name="msgType"></param>
    protected void Subscribe<T>(Action<T> onMessage) where T : MvxMessage
    {
        var token = this.Messenger.Subscribe<T>(onMessage);
        // Hold token to avoid GC of the subscription.
        _subscriptions.Add(token);
    }
    protected void SubscribeOnMainThread<T>(Action<T> onMessage) where T : MvxMessage
    {
        var token = this.Messenger.SubscribeOnMainThread<T>(onMessage);
        // Hold token to avoid GC of the subscription.
        _subscriptions.Add(token);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// OnDisappearing calls this.
    /// </summary>
    private void UnsubscribeAll()
    {
        if (_subscriptions.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (MvxSubscriptionToken token in _subscriptions)
            {
                // Per "https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/plugins/messenger", this is sufficient to Unsubscribe:
                // "Subscriptions can be cancelled at any time using the Unsubscribe method on the IMvxMessenger or by calling Dispose() on the subscription token."
                token.Dispose();
            }

            _subscriptions.Clear();
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

---

For view models, class would be "BaseViewModel", that your view models inherit from. Contents similar to above, but different method names for Appearing/Disappearing.

BaseViewModel.cs:

```
public class BaseViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    ...
    // mvvmcross' MvxViewModel provides these.
    protected override void ViewAppearing()
    {
        ...
    }
    protected override void ViewDisappearing()
    {
        ...
    }

    ... Messenger Subscriptions methods ...
}
```